# How to elipsis a text base on the character not line or width?

Tags: css

Lets say i have this "I want to trim this text into 15 characters for example" then it will be like this "I want to limit..." for my email template

Is it possible with only css? I know it can be done with javascript but in this case i think it can't.

Comment: Email template and JS is not very good friends. Also not all email clients support some CSS. Use PHP `substr($str, 0, 15).'&hellip;'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify 15 Character exactly with Pure Css.

I have a offer, Maybe help you.

```css
div {

    font-size: 16px;

    font-family: Serif;

    width: 105px;

    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    overflow: hidden;

    white-space: nowrap;

}
```

```html
<div>I want to limit Text To 15 Characters</div>
```